# Bash - How to pass a variable from a script to while loop?

Tags: bash

I have this `scriptA.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0
total=$((total+1))
export total
```

and I want to put that script in a while loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

max=0
while [[ "$max" -lt 2 ]]; do
bash scriptA.sh
max=$(echo $total)
echo Max: $max
sleep 1
done
```

But the value of `$max` is always empty, this is the result that I want:

```
Max: 1
Max: 2
```

How should I pass a variable from a script to a while loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `.` instead of `bash` to execute the subscript in the current context rather than spawning a new one.
- That also removes the need to use `export`.
- Define `$total` in the main script and only alter it in the subscript.
- Copy the value of `$total` to `$max` directly, without `echo`.
- Apply indentation to make the code more readable.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

total=$(($total+1))
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0
max=0
while [[ "$max" -lt 2 ]]; do
    . scriptA.sh
    max=$total
    echo Max: $max
    sleep 1
done
```

Prints:

> Max: 1
>   Max: 2